# Deploy Azure with Native Code in MSVC

Tags: visual-c++, azure, native, visual-studio-2010

I have been looking around and cannot seem to find any good instructions for doing this so I am making a post (also, it is late now, so it may be due to my lack of coherent thought at this point). But in any event, I have created a small web application on to be hosted on Azure which is dependent on some native code. Everything works fine through the emulator, but when I package it (through MSVC 2010) and upload it to a cloud instance, the DLL is not found. Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

I have let the WebRole know that my DLL is a dependency and in the project I have the "Copy Always" property set on the DLL. Furthermore, I have built the DLL in 64-bit release mode as well. Is there anything else that I need to do to make sure this DLL is included in my package?

Comment: It might be that your DLL depends on something like perhaps Visual C++ runtime and that dependency in not present on Azure VMs. You can use Dependency Walker to find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue is that the DLL was being built with `/MD` instead of `/MT`. When I changed this, all worked well.